# Elastic Beanstalk (Django) deployment fails because of RDS InvalidParameterCombination

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a django app running on AWS using elastic beanstalk. Has been running for quite a while without any problems.

Just now upon deploying via CLI (`eb deploy`) I'm running into the following error:

```
ERROR: ...Reason: The following resource(s) failed to update: [AWSEBRDSDatabase].
ERROR: Updating RDS database named: [...] failed. Invalid storage size for engine name postgres and storage type standard: 15 (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: [...])
```

The error message contains the value `15`, and indeed, in the django application database configuration it says:

[image: storage size screenshot]

When I try to change that number to an arbitrary 25 GB and apply those changes, I run into yet another error:

`... Cannot upgrade postgres from 9.5.10 to 9.5.4. ...`

So there are two things I don't understand:

1. Why is the 15GB a problem all of a sudden?
2. Why would it attempt to "upgrade" from 9.5.10 to 9.5.4?

Explanations and solution suggestions much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

There seems to be a configuration mismatch in the database engine version.

Elastic Beanstalk config:

[image: eb db config screenshot]

RDS instance details:

[image: rds instance details screenshot]

Comment: did you try multiple modifications in your DB? AWS has a very strict policy for modifications. "However, you can't make further storage modifications for either six (6) hours or while the DB instance status is storage-optimization, whichever is longer."

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos I did not. There is a strange engine version mismatch, however. See updated question.

Comment: did you try to remove and reinstall your Postgres through config file? It sounds weird this mismatch.

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos Not sure I understand what you mean by "reinstall through config file"... Also: this is a production environment I have to be rather careful with.

Comment: If i where in your shoes, first of all i will clone my project in another Beanstalk application to be sure for the availability of my application. Then i will add some commands in my config file (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) like `yum remove postgres\*
mv /var/lib/pgsql /var/lib/old.pgsql
yum install postgres-YOURVERSION`

Comment: We suddenly experience this too. We have an EBS app that has been running for almost two years and suddenly it got messed up for no reason

Comment: @Yehonatan Have you had any luck solving the issue?

Comment: @creimers Yup. Contacted Amazon Support, we've had to create a new RDS instance with a snapshot of the original one, create a new EB environment that is disconnected from an RDS instance and then connect the new RDS with the new EB. Basically, when you create an EB environment you SHOULDN'T attach to it an RDS instance (via the panel) but rather just connect it regularly. That's it basically, if you didn't understand then send me a message and I'll explain it fully

Comment: @Yehonatan thanks. That's also what I ended up doing.